# Why homolytic fission of polar molecules is possible at higher temperature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, covalent-compounds

While studying alkanes I came across the nitration of alkanes using Nitric acid at very high temperature, which apparently follows "free radical" mechanisms, by formation of OH°  °NO2 free radical ! How "homolytic" cleavage of N-OH (a polar bond)  is possible at any temperature instead of heterolytic cleavage i.e formation of ions  ?

Comment: That's how molecules work. Use high enough temperature and they break. In this case stability of NO2 eases this.

Comment: It is possible for both ions and radicals to be produced and it all depends on the energy. Molecules have many excited states that 'cross' the ground state at high energy and certain bond extension and this means that radical or ions are produced depending on the conditions. NaI can form Na$\cdot$ + I$\cdot$, see A. Zewail Nobel prize lecture for pictures of the energy diagram.